# Why does this code fail with a non-planet command line argument?

Tags: c

I was working on a textbook example of a C program that will take command arguments and determine whether or not they are planets. This is the code I have created:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NUM_PLANETS 9

void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *planets[] = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn"
                        "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
    printf("Num args: %d\n", argc);
    
    int i, j;
    
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        //for every argument on the command line
        printf("arg: %d\n", i);
        for(j = 0; j < NUM_PLANETS; j++){
            //for every planet
            printf("j = %d\n", j); 
            if(strcmp(argv[i], planets[j]) == 0){
                //argument is a planet
                printf("%s is planet %d\n", argv[i], j + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("hello\n");
        //check planet status
        if(j == NUM_PLANETS){
            printf("%s is not a planet\n", argv[i]);
        }
        printf("hello\n");
    }
}
```

When given `.\planet.exe Jupiter Ted` the program returns:

```
Num args: 3
arg: 1
j = 0
j = 1
j = 2
j = 3
j = 4
Jupiter is planet 5
hello
hello
arg: 2
j = 0
j = 1
j = 2
j = 3
j = 4
j = 5
j = 6
j = 7
j = 8
```

Evidently, there seems to be an issue with the program reaching the if statement which checks if the argument did not match any of the planets, but only when an argument does not already meet this requirement.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: what's the expected output?...

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can slow the program down to a speed where you can watch what happens as it happens. When you see the program do something unexpected you've usually found a bug you need to fix. The rest of the time you have to correct your expectations.

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ERGg0nnpTcvY9JGc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The array

```
char *planets[] = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn"
                    "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
```

has only following 8 elements:

```
"Mercury"
"Venus"
"Earth"
"Mars"
"Jupiter"
"SaturnUranus"
"Neptune"
"Pluto"
```

because there are no commas between `"Saturn"` and `"Uranus"` and therefore they are concatenated and treated as one string literal.

For that reason, accessing `planets[8]` is invoking *undefined behavior*.

Add comma between them to fix.

Comment: side question, why does this code compile? i mean, also with `-Wall` i don't get any warning for that missing comma

Comment: If you have: `"Saturn" "Uranus"`, the compiler concatenates two adjacent string constants (separated by [optional] whitespace) together into one: `"SaturnUranus"`. It's a _feature_ to allow you to [safely] break up long strings into multiple lines. You were invoking this feature and didn't notice because the two strings were on separate lines.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had spent so long moving those print statements around looking for some sort of mistake. I had even counted the number of elements in the array to make sure there was nine! I would have never spotted this. I will work on getting a debugger set up for sure.